# How to get memory capacity of an RDS cluster instance?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I have my rds cluster and a cloudwatch alarm as in the below code. What I'm trying to do is to apply the threshold in the alarm to match 75% value from MAXIMUM DB CONNECTION level of database cluster instance.

Since there is a co-relation in between the instance type and maximum number of database connections, I've tried several methods to access the database instance type but none of them worked. Any clue?

```
const TestCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, "TestDbCluster", {
  engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({
    version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_09_2,
  }),
  instances: 1,
  instanceProps: {
    instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
      ec2.InstanceClass.T3,
      ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM,
    ),
    vpcSubnets: {
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    },
    vpc: vpc,
  },
  clusterIdentifier: "TestDbCluster",
});

const ConnectionsMetric = TestCluster.metricDatabaseConnections();
const dbConnectionsAlarm = ConnectionsMetric.createAlarm(this, "TestAlarm", {
  alarmName: DB - DbConnections - Alarm,
  threshold: ???,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first declare the `instanceType` as a constant, then access the size from there.

```
const instanceType = ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM)

const TestCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'TestDbCluster', {
                engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({version: rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_09_2}),
                instances: 1,
                instanceProps: {
                    instanceType: instanceType,
                    vpcSubnets: {
                        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
                    },
                    vpc: vpc,
                },
                clusterIdentifier: 'TestDbCluster',
            })


// Do your logic here 
instanceType.toString() // will return 't3.medium'


const ConnectionsMetric = TestCluster.metricDatabaseConnections()
            const dbConnectionsAlarm = ConnectionsMetric.createAlarm(this, 'TestAlarm', {
                alarmName: DB-DbConnections-Alarm,
                threshold: ???,
                evaluationPeriods: 1
            })
```